# Cloudformation template reported as missing attribute for available container

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I've created a CloudFormation template via `docker convert`. I tried to create a new stack from it, but I'm getting this error:

> service TCtest3-Geoserver1Service-nGukIu33pYo5 was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements. The closest matching container-instance 664eaab8a3fb483eab556ced467f8759 is missing an attribute required by your task.

As per the troubleshooting link, I tried to identify the missing attribute:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> ecs-cli check-attributes --task-def xmap-dev-docker-geoserver1 --container-instances 664eaab8a3fb483eab556ced467f8759
Container Instance  Missing Attributes
xmap-ecs-ec2-1      None
```

None are identified. Is it possible that the error message is misleading, and that it could signify another issue? Or is it possible that `ecs-cli check-attributes` might not identify a specific issue?

For info, my ECS cluster is running on an EC2 instance, and I am trying to deploy with EC2 launchtype, not Fargate.

Comment: Already had this error when a task definition requires a certain amount of CPU and RAM and no ECS instances have enough capacity to handle it.

Comment: It deployed successfully on the same cluster, but using launchtype: Fargate. I therefore assumed the host spec was good enough. But maybe Fargate tasks are more burstable, and hence less limited by the spec of the EC2 host?

Comment: Fargate has it's own memory/cpu combination requirements that you can find here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-cpu-memory-error.html. However, this has nothing to do with container placement. Container instances (which are EC2 instances) have their own memory and CPU limits depending on their instance type (ex: 2gb for t3.small). If the container you want to deploy doesn't fit in any container instances, you will get the error "unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements".